# configuring single level dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css

I am not too familiar with using jquery/css. I added the files for DropIt jquery plugin (http://dev7studios.com/dropit/).

I was looking to do **Hover Me** example. I could use help implementing it as my method is totally wrong. I plugged the code into my ruby on rails project.

application.html.slim:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/","application"
= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick"
= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js","application"
= javascript_include_tag "dropit.js","application"
= stylesheet_link_tag "dropit"
```

The end result looks like such...

[image]

Which is wrong. It should look like this...

[image]

And when you hover over Welcome, username that it will show the drop down menu.

Current code that has the wrong implementation of the jquery plugin:

**_header.html.slim**

```
  javascript:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.menu').dropit();
    });

  #header
    .wrapper
      .login_sec
        .col
        ul.dropit
          li.dropit-trigger.dropit-open
          a href="" 
            =image_tag "login_icon1.png"
            span 
              'Welcome, 
              = logged_in_user.username
                          ul.dropit-submenu
              li
                a href="#"  Some Action 1
              li
                a href="#"  Some Action 2
              li
                a href="#"  Some Action 3
              li
                a href="#"  Some Action 4

            =image_tag "profile_link_img.png", class: 'img'
        .col.col2
          a href="/conversations"
            =image_tag "login_icon2.png"
            span Messages
            / =image_tag "login_icon4.png", class: 'img4'
            span class="messbg_icon" =unread_messages(current_user)
            / =unread_messages(current_user)
        .col.col3
          a href="/logout" 
            =image_tag "login_icon3.png", class: 'img3'
```

Original code without the jquery plugin:

```
  #header
    .wrapper
      .login_sec
        .col
          a href="" 
            =image_tag "login_icon1.png"
            span 
              'Welcome, 
              = logged_in_user.username
            =image_tag "profile_link_img.png", class: 'img'
        .col.col2
          a href="/conversations"
            =image_tag "login_icon2.png"
            span Messages
            / =image_tag "login_icon4.png", class: 'img4'
            span class="messbg_icon" =unread_messages(current_user)
            / =unread_messages(current_user)
        .col.col3
          a href="/logout" 
            =image_tag "login_icon3.png", class: 'img3'
```

/assets/stylesheets/dropit.css:

```
.dropit {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-trigger { position: relative; }
.dropit .dropit-submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0; /* dropdown left or right */
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    min-width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-open .dropit-submenu { display: block; }
```

/assets/javascripts/dropit.js:

```
.dropit {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-trigger { position: relative; }
.dropit .dropit-submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0; /* dropdown left or right */
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    min-width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-open .dropit-submenu { display: block; }
```

Comment: Please create an example. Is really hard to read that code..

Comment: @AlexChar Sorry for the mess. The exact example I was looking for is on Dropit page http://dev7studios.com/dropit/ for their `Hover Me` example. As seen from my screenshot the menu is auto appearing without hovering.

Comment: I think you can give it a try to smartmenus. You can build hovering dropdown menus, and regular clickable menus. If you like I can post in an answer a simple code. http://www.smartmenus.org/

Comment: @BernieSF Never heard of it. But will research it. If you like you can post answer and I can accept.

Comment: @CorneliusWilson just to let you know, this smartmenu library works on any browser, and even changes to horizontal when the window is resized to a very small width, or the application runs on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made it far too complex. You can do a single level drop down menu with just HTML and a tiny bit of CSS.

The snippet below may look like a lot of code, but only a small part of it is needed to get it working technically. The rest is just to make it look a little nice, and you can customize it as much as you want. I've added comments to distinquish the parts.

And.. no JavaScript at all, let alone external libraries.

For an even better menu, that responds to clicks instead of just hover, you can have a look at [this great tutorial by Koen Kivits](http://koen.kivits.com/articles/pure-css-menu/).

```css
/* This is what you actually, technically need */
.menu {
    position: relative;
}

.menu .menu_items {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.menu:hover .menu_items {
    display: block;
}

/* Stuff below is for show, for clarity, for not showing the background 
   through the menu items, etc, and to make it look a little nice. You 
   can keep this simple, or go wild. But make it your own! :) */
.menu {
    color: grey;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.menu .menu_items {
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;        
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 7px;
    list-style: none;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.menu .menu_items a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
}
.menu .menu_items a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.content {
    background-color: skyblue;
}

i {
    font-style: normal;
    color: black;
    font: 'wingdings';
}

i.down:before {
  content: '\25BE';
}
```

```html
<!-- And here is all your HTML -->
<nav class="menu">
    <i class="guy"></i>Welcome admin!<i class="down"></i>
    <ul class="menu_items">
        <li><a href="">Action 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Action 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Action 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Action 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Action 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!-- And some fake content to show that the menu actually hovers over it. -->
<div class="content">
    Other content<br/>
    goes here
</div>
```

Comment: I think I found the issue even with my original code and yours. Your code works as expected in FireFox, but it is not compatible with Safari (I haven't tested IE). Your code running live on Safari looks just like the screenshot in my post with the menu already expanded not being CSS compliant. Do you know how even in your supplied code how I can fix it so it shows up properly for all browsers?

Comment: Sorry, no. I don't have Safari. I wouldn't know why that happens, though. I could imagine the hover not working, but then the menu shouldn't show at all.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is the use of Smartmenus. The use is very simple:

download the required files from http://www.smartmenus.org/download/
download jquery from http://jquery.com/download/
copy sm-core-css.css inside of your "css" folder, also, copy the folder "sm-blue" with all of their content inside the "css' folder.
copy jquery.smartmenus.js inside of your "js" folder.
copy jquery-1.11.1.min.js inside of your "js" folder.
reference the files in your head section of your html file

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.smartmenus.js"></script>
<link href="css/sm-core-css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/sm-blue/sm-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in your body section of your html, add a unordered list (ul)

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="sm sm-blue" style="z-index: 1001 !important; margin: auto">
    <li id="Home" title="back to home page">
        <a href="javascript:function1();" style="padding: 0px 10px">Top Opt1 </a>
    </li>
    <li id="AboutUs">
        <a href="#">Top Opt2</a>
        <ul>
           <li>
              <a href="javascript:function2()">Option1</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a href="javascript:function2()">Option2</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

-Finally, in your $(document).ready, add:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { $('#main-menu').smartmenus({ showTimeout: 0 }); });
```